# I need to get the user ID and add it in a column table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get the user ID and add it in a column in a table in MySQL.

The function already show keyword name, keyword id, etc.

Im trying to get user ID

```
//GET RECORD
$query="SELECT * FROM wp_rankie_keywords where keyword_id=$id";
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$query="update wp_rankie_keywords set user_id = $user_id where keyword_id=$id";
$rows=$wpdb->get_results($query);
$row =$rows[0];
$keyword = $row->keyword;
$keyword_site = $row->keyword_site;`
```

The plugin name is wp-rankie.

Comment: u mean the current users id? if so then `wp_get_current_user()` is your answer

Comment: what's the point of the `select` query? You don't execute it, and the variable gets trashed/replaced with your `update` query text.

Comment: I tried $user_id = wp_get_current_user();
        $query="SELECT * FROM wp_rankie_keywords where keyword_id=$id and user_id=$user_id";  and not working.

Comment: where do you get $id from? you use it in both queries (aside from that the first query is never executed), but did you check if it is a valid value?

Comment: I would like to know how to define it and how to get this User_id, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

insert as line 4:

```
 $wpdb->query($query);
```

this will execute the query in line 3.
then create a new query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM wp_rankie_keywords where keyword_id=$id and user_id=$user_id";
```

and execute the get_results on this query.

Comment: I tried $user_id = wp_get_current_user();
        $query="SELECT * FROM wp_rankie_keywords where keyword_id=$id and user_id=$user_id";  and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_rankie_keywords WHERE keyword_id=%d AND user_id=%d", $id, $user_id);
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Can you add var_dump($query) after $query = $wpdb->prepare... then check the query?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /membri/cristihost/wp-content/plugins/wp-rankie/r-functions.php on line 65

Comment: Did you add ";" after the var_dump($query)?
var_dump($query);

Comment: Yes, i added ; after it.

Comment: Can you share r-functions.php with me?

Comment: This is original file: http://pastebin.com/brFAm9ah, i need to add user id to column "user_id" in wp-rankie_keywords.

Comment: First, you need to add new column to the wp_rankie_keywords table. you can do it mysql client application such as using mysql query browser or sqlyog. 
Second, you will need to query the values with id and user_id. I already gave it on my previous code.

Comment: I created it, please give me the r-functions.php file updated.